# Sobrescribir una columna de un dataframe dependiendo del valor de otra columna

Tags: python, pandas

hola a todos estoy trabajando con pandas y quiero llenar los NaN de una columna si otra columna tiene un valor especifico como puedo hacer eso? estoy intentando
`df['price_psqm_mxn_lot_size'] = df['price_psqm_mxn_lot_size'].replace(np.nan, 0) if df[df.lot_size==0] else np.nan` 
pero me sale error alguna sugerencia?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_43124/3651626384.py in <module>
----> 1 df['price_psqm_mxn_lot_size'] = df['price_psqm_mxn_lot_size'].replace(np.nan, 0) if df[df.lot_size==0] else np.nan

E:\trabajo\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1535     @final
   1536     def __nonzero__(self):
-> 1537         raise ValueError(
   1538             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1539             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: El problema es la condición. Recuerda que al hacer operaciones lógicas se te devuelve una matriz con booleanos. Puedes usar `apply`

Comment: intente esto pero me sale el mismo error `df['price_psqm_mxn_lot_size'] = df['price_psqm_mxn_lot_size'].apply(lambda x : 0 if (df.lot_size==0) else x)`

Comment: Sigues cometiendo el mismo error.  El error es en `if (df.lot_size==0)`.  Al usar `apply` se de devuelve el valor de cada fila, que sería `x`. Lo que tienes que hacer es comparar ese valor. `0 if x==0 else x` sería la condición.

Comment: tienes razón, pero en este caso necesito comparar con el valor de una columna diferente a la que le estoy enviando

Comment: Entonces debe obtener el índice del elemento así comparar índices. No recuerdo muy bien como era, hace tiempo no he tocado python. Te puedo decir una forma muy ineficiente de lograrlo `df['price_psqm_mxn_lot_size'] = [0 if df.lot_size[i] == 0 else df.price_psqm_mxn_lot_size[i] for i in range(len(df))]`

Comment: Es ineficiente por que no se recomienda usar bucles cuando se trabaja con pandas. Se recomienda usar las operaciones matriciales que trae por defecto en sus métodos ya que están optimizadas.

Comment: Lo logre sacar de esta manera `df['lot_size'] = np.where(df['lot_size'].isna()), 0, df['lot_size'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar una combinación entre [`pandas.DataFrame.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) y [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) para lograrlo

Utilizando el siguiente `dataframe` como ejemplo (Archivo "sample.csv")

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | nan |
| 2 | nan | 3 |
| 3 | 4 | 4 |
| 4 | 5 | nan |
| 5 | nan | 6 |

Voy a sustituir los valores `NaN` de la columna A únicamente si la columna B es igual a 3

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
df['A'].fillna(df['B'].apply(lambda x: x if x==3 else np.nan), inplace=True)
```

Al imprimir el `dataframe` obtenemos:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | nan |
| 2 | 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 | 4 |
| 4 | 5 | nan |
| 5 | nan | 6 |

El `apply` crea una serie que será utilizada por `fillna` para reemplazar los valores `NaN`